# How to prevent RowValidating event when a new row is added to a RadGridView - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, radgridview

I have a Telerik RadGridView where users can add rows and edit inline. I am using the RowValidating event to ensure that users don't leave a row without filling in the necessary fields.

However, the RowValidating event has started to get called when adding a new row which means that the new row is showing in red as soon as it is created as the user hasn't filled in the necessary fields yet.
How can I prevent the RowValidating event from being called (or know to ignore it) when a new row is being added?

NOTE: I can't just check whether there is no data and return at the start of the method if so, as I want to handle that scenario differently to allow users to delete empty rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the EditOperationType of the GridViewRowValidatingEventArgs.

Add the following line to the beginning of the RowValidating method:

```
if (e.EditOperationType == GridViewEditOperationType.None) return;
```

This will skip the rest of the method if it is adding a new row.

NOTE: I don't know why the EditOperationType is 'None' when adding a new row rather than 'Insert', but that is what it seems to be.